# php included html site does not show images - just in one case

Tags: php, html, image, path

after reading about php path-issues i tested really basic stuff and it is still confusing me. I hope to at least get some keywords for an more effective search.

I have a Folder called 'img' in my rootdirectory. additional i put the image in the root directory itself.

This does not work - points to imagefolder img:
    `<img src="/img/mypicture.jpg" width="135" height="184" alt="picture.jpg class="fleft" />`

But this works fine, points to imagecopy in rootfolder:
    `<img src="/mypicture.jpg" width="135" height="184" alt="picture.jpg" class="fleft" />`

without slash too it is fine too:
`<img src="mypicture.jpg" width="135" height="184" alt=picture.jpg" class="fleft" />`

Well, i feel really stupid. This is an absolute path in every case right?
Why is it working in the second/third code-statement? 
But i like to get it working for the first statement as well. All i got is the alt="" statement. After reading and trying for hours i hope there is a solution which is not simple ;)

Have a nice day
Gerd

Edit 1+2: The Html is located in a folder at the same level as the img folder. both are in the root directory.

../img

../websites

Comment: If you write slash -> absolute. W/o -> relative to the actual adress bar. Where is your html located?

Comment: edit1: html site is located at the same level as the img folder. rootdirectory/img and rootdirectory/websites ;

Comment: If you are putting your img in your root directory, it's not inside "img" folder, if your html is in your root, then you can use either src="mypicture.jpg" or src="/mypicture.jpg". I just can't define by your question if your problem is the second and third code-statement not working, or the first one (First you say that your code on 2 and 3 is working, but after it you ask why they aren't...)

Comment: Sorry terrible mistake, i want to get the first statement to work, but only the testsetup (2 and 3) is working.

Comment: Create a directory `img` put the images in that directory. Your first example should work. With your edit,  you need to refer to the img folder as `.. /img/picture.gif `

Comment: I don't think this is a PHP question...

Comment: @Jhecht thats the problem, i have that setup already. I tested many statements (without plan) like ../img/picture.jpg or /img/picture.jpg or img/picture.jpg and so on. Nothing worked.

Comment: @Adrian7 , you may be right, it may not be a php problem. But i am not sure. Because i included the files, which may affect the path calculations? Just loading the html site does not cause any problem.

Comment: Path calculations are done through the file being requested, not the ones being included. Otherwise you'd never be able to reliably include anything.

Comment: In your Web page right click and select inspect element. The file path should be highlighted like a link. Click on it, see if the image shows up.

Comment: i read this, thats why i thought it is important who includes too: http://yagudaev.com/posts/resolving-php-relative-path-problem/ Anyway i need only help to know how to close the question. Well, i got it to work (deleted everything build it from scratch - as a testdirectory) but its the same structure as before. If i find our about the solution of the error i just post again. Have a nice day everyone and thanks for the replies!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first block of html, you are missing a quotation mark.

You have:
    alt="picture.jpg class

It should be: 
    alt="picture.jpg" class

If your HTML file is in the same directory as your "img" folder it will work.

However, if your HTML file is in a folder that is in the same directory as the "img" folder, then you must navigate out of this folder first before trying to enter "img".

E.g: "../img/mypicture.jpg"

Comment: thank you, i would never have guessed that. I looked over it but was to blind. I was sure that i had copied all the statements, so that couldn't happen. But i made a mistake! This is the end of confusion, thank you again.